# list of figures and tables when there are no figures or tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a rather large project, from which I select portions based on needs. This selection is done using a complex system of `\include` and `\input` commands. I would like to generate a list of figures and a list of tables for the output, but in the case there are no figures the list of figures should not appear. The same should happen with tables.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}


\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\def\ignoreTable#1\end{table}{}
\def\ignoreFigure#1\end{figure}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Table}
\listoftables

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Where if I write

```
\def\ignoreTable{\relax}
\def\ignoreFigure{\relax}
```

just after `\begin{document}` the output is:

[image]

---

Ideally, there would be an "elegant" macro or package, that would eliminate the list of tables, including its entry in the TOC, if there are not tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another approach. What it does is to check at the end of the document the values of the `figure` and `table` counters, and add to the `.aux` file a boolean flag setting depending on whether these values are zero or positive.

Then you have on next run `\iffigures` and `\iftables` which allow you to act conditionally.

In the code below, perhaps the `\global` are not really needed, I didn't check.

See also a variant at bottom which does not use the `figure`/`table` counters because they might well be reset to zero due to document sectioning (as pointed out by `egreg` in a comment).

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\newif\iffigures
\newif\iftables

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument {%
    \if@filesw
       \ifnum\value{figure}=\z@ % no figures
          \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\figuresfalse}%
       \else
          \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\figurestrue}%
       \fi
       \ifnum\value{table}=\z@ % no tables
          \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\tablesfalse}%
       \else
          \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\tablestrue}%
       \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother 

% for the purpose of testing

% this will make a MWE without tables
\long\def\IGNORE #1\ENDIGNORE{}

% uncomment to make a MWE with tables
% \let\IGNORE\empty
% \let\ENDIGNORE\empty

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% 
\iffigures
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
   \listoffigures
\fi

% 
\iftables
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Table}
   \listoftables
\fi

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\IGNORE
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\ENDIGNORE
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\IGNORE
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\ENDIGNORE
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

Here is for a document with figures but no tables:

[image: without tables]

And if tables are present:

[image: with tables]

Three compilations needed.

Variant. I don't know to what extent patching `\figure` and `\table` as here is OK, depends perhaps on float related packages. At the worst I guess doing the patches immediately after `\begin{document}` should be enough (at the end of preamble might not be enough if some package does stuff during At Begin Document).

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\newif\iffigures
\newif\iftables

\makeatletter

\let\OLDfigure\figure
\def\figure {\figures@in@document\OLDfigure }
\let\OLDtable\table
\def\table  {\tables@in@document\OLDtable }

\def\figures@in@document {%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\figurestrue}%
    \global\let\figures@in@document\empty
}

\def\tables@in@document {%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\tablestrue}%
    \global\let\tables@in@document\empty
}

\makeatother

% for the purpose of testing

% this will make a MWE without tables
\long\def\IGNORE #1\ENDIGNORE{}

% uncomment to make a MWE with tables
%\let\IGNORE\empty
%\let\ENDIGNORE\empty

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% 
\iffigures
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
   \listoffigures
\fi

% 
\iftables
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Table}
   \listoftables
\fi

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\IGNORE
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\ENDIGNORE
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\IGNORE
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\ENDIGNORE
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an `s` missing at the end of the `List of Table` thing in the TOC, was copied over from OP's code.

Comment: Good idea, but it won't work in case figure or table numbers are reset at chapter/sections and the last chapter/section has no table or figures. The `totcount` package may make your life easier, because it takes care of the writing in the `.aux` file.

Comment: @egreg I updated my answer, I do not have time to checkout the `totcount` package until later.

Comment: I tried to use several methods. Until recently the concept of adding a label at the end of the document worked fine. After some updates it stopped working, I use it in a class I created for a document I am writing. So I tried all the counter methods and several other without success,  the second approach is the only one that worked for me.  I expanded it, as did before, to work for the glossary build with datagidx and the Todo list. For the glossary it took a few 'redefines', but that is part of the process if you want to do something that out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 6):

In order to add the lists to the table of contents, I recommend using `tocbibind`, which ensures correct page numbers even if the lists go on for more than one page.

The trick is to measure the contents of the `.lof` or `.lot` files: if they don't produce any output, we omit them, but we still initiate their production.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\floatstyle{boxed}


\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\def\ignoreTable#1\end{table}{}
\def\ignoreFigure#1\end{figure}{}
%\def\ignoreTable{}
%\def\ignoreFigure{}

\makeatletter
\let\tocbibind@tocfile\tocfile
\renewcommand{\tocfile}[2]{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{\@input{\jobname.#2}}
  \ifdim\ht\z@>\z@
    \tocbibind@tocfile{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    % do the same as \@starttoc without the \@input instruction
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#2\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#2\endcsname \jobname.#2\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

With the uncommented definitions of `\ignoreTable` and `\ignoreFigure` we get none of them and the output is

[image]

If I enable figures but not tables, the output is

[image]

Finally, if I enable tables and figures, I get

[image]

---

### Alternative method

With an up-to-date TeX distribution, the `assoccnt` package is available and a much safer test can be used using it along with `totcount`.

Change the code above into

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\usepackage{totcount,assoccnt}
\newtotcounter{totallof}
\newtotcounter{totallot}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totallof}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totallot}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\def\ignoreTable#1\end{table}{}
\def\ignoreFigure#1\end{figure}{}
%\def\ignoreTable{}
%\def\ignoreFigure{}

\makeatletter
\let\tocbibind@tocfile\tocfile
\renewcommand{\tocfile}[2]{%
  \ifnum\totvalue{total#2}>\z@ % there are figures or tables
    \tocbibind@tocfile{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    % do the same as \@starttoc without the \@input instruction
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#2\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#2\endcsname \jobname.#2\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can measure the lists and discard them if they only have a heading:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\def\wheninteresting#1{%
\setbox0\vbox{#1}%
\ifdim\ht0>35pt
\unvbox0
\fi}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\def\ignoreTable#1\end{table}{}
\def\ignoreFigure#1\end{figure}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\wheninteresting{
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
}

\wheninteresting{
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Table}
\listoftables
}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreFigure
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\ignoreTable
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you leave @Yossi's `\def\ignoreTable#1\end{table}{}` as is on purpose, despite the fact that it results in `tabletable` in the output (the first from the `\def` the second from the fact that only up to and included the `\end` was gobbled) ?

Comment: David Carlisle, is safe use the value `35pt` on `\ifdim\ht0>35pt`? Because my empty header could be bigger than `35pt`, or my header plus a list only with one item could be smaller than `35pt`. Is there a way to compute the header size, so there is not need to use a hard coded value of `35pt`?

Comment: @user sorry I don't know what you mean, it is much better to make a real complete example and post as a new question than ask as a comment on a 4 year old answer.

Comment: David Carlisle, new questions here: 1) [How to dynamically calculate the height of an empty list of things?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515757/how-to-dynamically-calculate-the-height-of-an-empty-list-of-things); 2) [Why \pdfbookmark keeps adding to the PDF bookmarks while \addcontentsline{toc} does not add the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515759/why-pdfbookmark-keeps-adding-to-the-pdf-bookmarks-while-addcontentslinetoc-d)