# Don't display List of Tables when no tables present (including long tables)

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable

I am using a variant of the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234398/list-of-figures-and-tables-when-there-are-no-figures-or-tables) to remove the List of Figures and List of Tables part of the contents when none are there. The issue I have is when using longtable, if there is only a single longtable and no other table, the List of Tables gets removed as the following line (I believe) does not account for long tables. What do I need to do to amend this?

```
\def\tables@in@document {%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\tablestrue}%
    \global\let\tables@in@document\empty
}
```

MWE below

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}

\newif\iffigures
\newif\iftables

\makeatletter

\let\OLDfigure\figure
\def\figure {\figures@in@document\OLDfigure }
\let\OLDtable\table
\def\table  {\tables@in@document\OLDtable }

\def\figures@in@document {%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\figurestrue}%
    \global\let\figures@in@document\empty
}

\def\tables@in@document {%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux {\global\string\tablestrue}%
    \global\let\tables@in@document\empty
}

\makeatother

% for the purpose of testing

% this will make a MWE without tables
\long\def\IGNORE #1\ENDIGNORE{}

% uncomment to make a MWE with tables
%\let\IGNORE\empty
%\let\ENDIGNORE\empty

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% 
\iffigures
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
   \listoffigures
\fi

% 
\iftables
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
   \listoftables
\fi

\section{First section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\LaTeX
\caption{my figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
\LaTeX\TeX
\caption{another figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[\inputlineno]

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\LaTeX
\caption{my table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[\inputlineno]
\IGNORE
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\TeX\TeX
\caption{another table}
\end{table}
\ENDIGNORE
\lipsum[\inputlineno]

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the same for `longtable` as you did for `table`.

```
...
\let\OLDlongtable\longtable
\def\longtable  {\tables@in@document\OLDlongtable }
...
```

BTW You should have enclosed the first `table` within an `\IGNORE` `\ENDIGNORE` pairing.